# Protractor/Selenium: run browser in the background

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm using protractor for testing.  99% of the times there's no need to actually see the browser, the tests take a long time, and all we're interested in is the final outcome.
Is there a way to hide the browser opened for testing (e.g. run in the background)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated before, [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) works wonders.  The only browser not supported by docker-selenium is Internet Explorer, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you cannot really reliably control the way browser windows are opened via protractor/webdriverjs/selenium.

A common way to approach the problem is to use a **virtual display**, see:

- [Can Selenium Webdriver open browser windows silently in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background)

An alternative way to accomplish that, would be to run tests inside a [`docker-selenium`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) container, here is a quite detailed introduction:

- [protractor with any headless browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360592/protractor-with-any-headless-browser)

Or, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361778/771848) and if you are on Mac OS X, you can run selenium tests on the same machine but under a different user which would not interfere with your current display.

You can also run protractor tests in a docker container in a headless firefox:

- [Protractor-Firefox-Headless-Docker](https://github.com/cfalguiere/Protractor-Firefox-Headless-Docker)

---

Another alternative would be to use a remote selenium server, as, for example, [`BrowserStack`](http://www.browserstack.com/) or [`Sauce Labs`](https://saucelabs.com/) services provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try headless browser like PhantomJS for this purpose. PhantomJS runs in background and failures can be captured using screenshot.
Refer following link to know more about phantomjs:
[Protractor running tests on PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058910/protractor-running-tests-on-phantomjs)

Comment: Note: protractor developers don't recommend using PhantomJS with protractor - you'll quickly easily get into wonderful world of weird errors and magic behavior.