# Test hover state changes with protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

No matter what I do I can’t get the hover state functional with protractor tests. The following code is semi functional ..

- Works well in Firefox
- Only works when I scroll the area into view with Chrome.
- Fails in Phantom JS

---

```
obj
  .getCssValue('color')
  .then(function (color1) {
    browser
      .actions()
      .mouseMove(obj)
      .perform()
      .then(function () {
        obj
          .getCssValue('color')
          .then(function (color2) {
            expect(color1)
              .not
              .toEqual(color2);
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 5):

We've encountered something similar recently.

What helped us was to *wait for an element to have a specific CSS value using [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)*:

```
function waitForCssValue (elementFinder, cssProperty, cssValue) {
    return function () {
        return elementFinder.getCssValue(cssProperty).then(function (actualValue) {
            return actualValue === cssValue;
        });
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
browser.wait(waitForCssValue(obj, 'color', color2), 5000);
```

Here, we are basically waiting up to 5 seconds for a CSS `color` value to be equal to `color2`. Apply the wait call right after you hover the element.

---

Also, I remember having that scrolling into view helped to resolve similar issues on SO:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", obj);
```

---

Maximizing browser window can also help, we usually do it in `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
},
```

---

Additional note about `PhantomJS`:

First of all, protractor developers recommend against running `protrator` end-to-end tests with `PhantomJS`:

> Note: We recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor.
>   There are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving
>   differently from real browsers.

Aside from that, see:

- [Using Protractor with PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086961/using-protractor-with-phantomjs)

Here I'm trying to get to the point, that you should sacrifice the "Fails in Phantom JS" argument.

Comment: I’ve tried `browser.executeScript`, but it doesn’t work; Any tricks about it?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck thanks for trying it out! What are the symptoms, do you see the element is getting focused and hovered in the browser? Any errors? Have you tried the "wait" approach?

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1 :***

Just use a simple hover function for your object

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p onmouseover="colorin(this)" onmouseout="colorout(this)">
Testing colorin and colorout function for mouse hover
</p>


<script>
function colorout(x) {
    x.style.color = "#000000";
}

function colorin(x) {
    x.style.color = "#7FAF00";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***Possible Solution 2 :***

Try this version with waitForAngular(); you may need to wait for angular :

```
obj
  .getCssValue('color')
  .then(function (color1) {
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser
      .actions()
      .mouseMove(obj)
      .perform()
      .then(function () {
        obj
          .getCssValue('color')
          .then(function (color2) {
            expect(color1)
              .not
              .toEqual(color2);
          });
      });
```

***Possible Solution 3 :***

Replace `.mouseMove(obj)` with `.mouseMove(browser.findElement(protractor.B.id('foo')))` and adapt it to your code

Comment: This page doesn’t use any Angular

Comment: Ok... you could then just use the first solution or integrate `.onmouseover` and `.onmouseout` to your current function instead of `.mouseMove` ... any way this issue seems to be know for protractor https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/159

Comment: Right, but that would require JS to do everything CSS does, which is a non-starter